# Is it possible to create a share link to a specific location in a Word Online document?

Tags: word-online

I would like to be able to send a link to a colleague, which will take him to a specific location in the document when the document opens in the Word Online web application.

For example, a programmer who needs to see a small section of a large document. I want the document to open directly to the specified heading.

Is this possible? To a heading? A bookmark?